# Is there a way to get rspec --bisect to work with jruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec, jruby, bisect

I thought I'd try using `rspec --bisect` to figure out which combinations of tests caused a failure, but it turns out that this doesn't work with JRuby, or at least, not when launching `org.jruby.Main` via java, which is how all our automated tests are set up.

The way bisect apparently works is that it launches a child rspec process.

What actually happens is...

```
Stderr:
sh: uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/bin/jruby: No such file or directory
```

Apparently rspec tells `sh` to run the command for some reason. And because the command is inside the jar, this obviously can't work. If it had executed rspec directly, that might work because `rspec` is a Ruby executable and JRuby might treat that differently. (There sure is a lot of "might" in here, though.)

So what I'm wondering is, is there some quick fix I can apply here to make rspec use some other method to launch the child process? Maybe it doesn't need to launch a new process? Or maybe there is a way to tell it how to launch the child process?

Comment: *"figure out which combinations of tests caused a failure"* what is this supposed to mean? if these "combinations" are inside an `it` block then [`aggregate_failures`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/aggregating-failures) might be useful to you.

Comment: @engineersmnky Suppose that you have 100 examples in a spec, and example 72 fails when you run all 100 examples, but when you run _just_ example 72, it passes. You could run different combinations of tests manually to figure out which test is leaky, but an alternative is to run `rspec --bisect` and go and get a coffee while it figures this out via some kind of binary search.

Comment: @Trejkaz Hei! I know this is over a year late, but... I'm currently running a bisection under jruby and prompt is hanged a "Running suite to find failures...", but no errors (yet). Do you recommend that I go get a coffee, or this is not going to work at all?

Comment: @deivid good question... I guess it depends on how long the suite takes normally too, but it's going to run it many, many times, so I usually do that sort of thing over the weekend, in which case I can fit in many coffees.